# what does object Calendar do?

Tags: java, calendar

I had a test for object Calendar:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            System.out.println(calendar.get(i));


output:
1
2011
6
28
2
6
187
4
1
1
10
```

My question is how can that happen? There are also the same tricky problems for api **calendar.get()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see what the problem is. The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) states that you get the specific values for whatever field ID you provide.

You would normally use the field constants to get specific values (like `DAY_OF_MONTH` or `MONTH` but any integer will do provided it's within the range `0..FIELD_COUNT`.

The field IDs are documented [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util) (though this may change in future) so your specific values are:

```
ID  Value  Description
--  -----  -----------
 0      1  Era (BC/AD for Gregorian).
 1   2011  Year.
 2      6  Month (zero-based).
 3     28  Week-of-year.
 4      2  Week-of-month.
 5      6  Date/day-of-month.
 6    187  Day-of-year.
 7      4  Day-of-week.
 8      1  Day-of-week-in-month.
 9      1  AM/PM selector.
10     10  Hour.
```

That's `July 6, 2011 AD`, somewhere between `10:00:00 PM` and `10:59:59 PM` inclusive. The minutes and seconds values are field IDs 12 and 13 and your code doesn't print them out, hence the uncertainty on the time.

Answer (score 4):

In [`Calendar.get(i)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) `i` represents a field such as `ERA`, `YEAR`, `MONTH`, etc..

For example,  `calendar.get(1)` is the same as `calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The API provided by `java.util.Calendar` is not very well designed as your confusion illustrates. However take a look at the [JavaDoc for get()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29). The int value is meant to represent the field you want to get the value of. See all of the members listed at that JavaDoc described as "Field number ..." such as [`YEAR`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#YEAR). So `calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)` would equal `2011`.

Answer (score 0):

The Calendar class is an overkill for many common Date related scenarios. The history is somewhat as follows : The Date class was found to have many deficiencies w.r.t manipulating date objects. Hence the Calendar class was introduced. However, the Calendar class has proved to be an over-engineered solution to many of the common date related scenarios.

Read the Javadoc for better understanding of the Calendar class.